# Project nearing completion. Time to begin testing. Which methods are feasible towards the end of the development cycle?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, testing-strategies

Let's assume one joins a project near the end of its development cycle.  The project has been passed on across many teams and has been an overall free-for-all with no testing whatsoever taking place along the whole time.  The other members on this team have no knowledge of testing (shame!) and unit testing each method seems infeasible at this point.

What would the recommended strategy for testing a product be at this point, besides usability testing?  Is this normally the point where you're stuck with manual point-and-click expected output/actual output work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically take a bottom-up approach to testing, but I think in this case you want to go top-down.  Test the biggest components you can wrap unit-tests around and see how they fail.  Those failures should point you towards what sub-components need tests of their own.  You'll have a pretty spotty test suite when this is done, but it's a start.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the budget for it, get a testing automation suite. HP/Mercury QuickTest is the leader in this space, but is very expensive.  The idea is that you record test cases like macros by driving your GUI through use cases.  You fill out inputs on a form (web, .net, swing, pretty much any sort of GUI), the engine learns the form elements names. Then you can check for expected output on the GUI and in the db.  Then you can plug in a table or spreadsheet of various test inputs, including  invalid cases where it should fail and run it through hundreds of scenarios if you like.  After the tests are recorded, you can also edit the generated scripts to customize them.  It builds a neat report for you in the end showing you exactly what failed.

There are also some cheap and free GUI automation testing suites that do pretty much the same thing but with fewer features.  In general the more expensive the suite, the less manual customizition is necessary.  Check out this list: http://www.testingfaqs.org/t-gui.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this is where a good Quality Assurance test would come in.  Write out old fashioned test cases and hand out to multiple people on the team to test.

Answer (score 0):

> What would the recommended strategy for testing a product be at this point, besides usability testing?

I'd recommend code inspection, by someone/people who know (or who can develop) the product's functional specification.

An extreme, purist way would be to say that, because it "has been an overall free-for-all with no testing whatsoever", therefore one can't trust any of it: not the existing testing, nor the code, nor the developers, nor the development process, nor management, nothing about the project. Furthermore, testing doesn't add quality to software (quality has to be built-in, part of the development process). The only way to have a quality product is to build a quality product; this product had no quality in its build, and therefore one needs to rebuild it:

- Treat the existing source code as a throw-away prototype or documentation
- Build a new product piece-by-piece, optionally incorporating suitable fragments (if any) of the old source code.

But doing code inspection (and correcting defects found via code inspection) might be quicker. That would be in addition to functional testing.

Whether or not you'll want to not only test it but also spend the extra time effort to develop automated tests depends on whether you'll want to maintain the software (i.e., in the future, to change it in any way and then retest it).

You'll also need:

- Either:

  - Knowledge of the functional specification (and non-functional specification)
  - Developers and/or QA people with a clue
- Or:

  - A small, simple product
  - Patient, forgiving end-users
  - Continuing technical support after the product is delivered

Answer (score 0):

One technique that I incorporate into my development practice when entering a project at this time in the lifecycle is to add unit tests as defects are reported (by QA or end users). You won't get full code coverage of the existing code base, but at least this way future development can be driven and documented by tests. Also this way you should be assured that your tests fail before working on the implementation. If you write the test and it doesn't fail, the test is faulty.

Additionally, as you add new functionality to the system, start those with tests so that at least those sub-systems are tested. As the new systems interact with existing, try adding tests around the old boundary layers and work your way in over time. While these won't be Unit tests, these integration tests are better than nothing.

Refactoring is yet another prime target for testing. Refactoring without tests is like walking a tight rope without a net. You may get to the other side successfully, but is the risk worth the reward?